# dompdf - grinds to a halt when I specify a4, landscape

Tags: php, dompdf

This is a bit niche, hoping someone can help.

I'm using [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to convert HTML into PDF files - nice piece of kit using existing library infrastructure. However, when I specify the 'set_paper' method it goes completely mental, sucking CPU out of existence and crashing. Odd, to say the least. It works when you do not specify this.

Code:-

```
            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'landscape');
        $dompdf->render();


        file_put_contents('data.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

Comment: Presumably the problem happens when you call `render()`, not just because you have called `set_paper`? This likely has to do with your HTML and were I to guess I'd say the problem is likely related to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=91). To make better sense of your problem it would help if you could post a sample HTML document that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it works when in portrait and not landscape, it probably has to do with a table being taller than one page. There is a bug that causes DOMPDF to crash if a table extends beyond one page. Either surround the content with another element like a div, or break the table apart into several tables.

Answer (score 9):

I had an issue with the landscape, because i was using

```
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'landscape');
```

after the

```
$dompdf->render();
```

Correct order:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
```